# Convert BPM xml file BPM diagram

Tags: flowable

How to convert bpm XML file to bpm diagram? I am failing to do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to know what type of BPM is, they will all follow BPMN 2.0 design ideas and see if the API has any examples of using flow charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can import process on that link after that you can see diagram.
http://localhost:8080/flowable-modeler/#/processes